# CSS3 Overlay Target One Click – Two Transitions

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS3 div overlay. From left to right. Would it be possible to move (slide) the id „content“ from right to left after click on „open it“?

http://jsfiddle.net/PpQTB/3/

```
.overlay-target:target {
    right: 0;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#content
{
/* right to left after click to overlay */
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna say that you'd be be better of using JQ/JQ since you can't target two elements at the same time in CSS.

Comment: Yes, why not. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE for @tobiv's suggestion using transforms:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PpQTB/7/)**

```
#content {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5199s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-target:target + #content {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

ORIGINAL:

You can do something similar to what you are already doing. You'll need to tweak the timing:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PpQTB/5/)**

```
#content {
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.5199s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-target:target + #content {
    margin-left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `transform` or `position` instead of `margin`. But then you'll also need some sort of clipping/hidden overflow to prevent horizontal scrolling...

Comment: @tobiv, I updated the answer to include a `transform` option. Clipping will be difficult here because animating `clip` requires using `px`.